# In tikzposters, I want to Use two \begin{column} \end{column} in one document class, it gives undesired results

Tags: tikzposter

[image]

Everyone, please help me on this, my project is dependent on the outcome of this coding. I am trying to create a poster using `tikzposter`, and I have different columns and sub-column width which i need to place at the same time in a single output, so what i was trying to do was, put **two** `\begin{column}` and `\end{column}` to get the desired result. Apparently it is not working, the **second** `\begin{column}` and `\end{column}` are getting overlapped on the first.

Can you guys please help me understand, how should i have the layout of the following columns:

Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[25pt, ,Landscape, margin=0mm, innermargin=0mm, blockverticalspace=5mm, colspace=0mm, subcolspace=-20mm]{tikzposter}
\geometry{paperwidth=60in,paperheight=20in}
\makeatletter
\setlength{\TP@visibletextwidth}{\textwidth-2\TP@innermargin}
\setlength{\TP@visibletextheight}{\textheight-2\TP@innermargin}
\makeatother
\tikzposterlatexaffectionproofoff
\usetitlestyle{Empty} %<-- Deletes the title on the Top of the poster.
\title{}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{2em}
\begin{document}
\begin{columns}
    \column{0.49}
        \block{}
    {
        \textbf{First Column}
    }
    \begin{subcolumns}  
    \subcolumn{0.5}         
    \block{}
    {
        \textbf{First SubColumn}
    }
    \block{}
    {
        \textbf{First.1 SubColumn}
    }
        \subcolumn{0.5}         
    \block{}
    {
        \textbf{Second SubColumn}
    }
    \block{}
    {
        \textbf{Second.1 SubColumn}
    }
\end{subcolumns}
    \column{0.49}
    \block{}
    {
        \textbf{Second Column}
    }
    \begin{subcolumns}  
        \subcolumn{0.5}         
        \block{}
        {
            \textbf{third SubColumn}
        }
        \block{}
        {
            \textbf{third.1 SubColumn}
        }
        \subcolumn{0.5}         
        \block{}
        {
            \textbf{Forth SubColumn}
        }
        \block{}
        {
            \textbf{Forth.1 SubColumn}
        }
\end{subcolumns}
\end{columns}
%----------------------------------------------------------------For Next set of Columns    
\begin{columns}
    \column{0.45}
    \block{}
    {
        \textbf{First Column}
    }
    \begin{subcolumns}  
        \subcolumn{0.5}         
        \block{}
        {
            \textbf{Alpha SubColumn}
        }
        \block{}
        {
            \textbf{Alpha.1 SubColumn}
        }
        \subcolumn{0.5}         
        \block{}
        {
            \textbf{Beta SubColumn}
        }
        \block{}
        {
            \textbf{Beta.1 SubColumn}
        }
    \end{subcolumns}
    \column{0.45}
    \block{}
    {
        \textbf{Beta Column}
    }
    \begin{subcolumns}  
        \subcolumn{0.33}        
        \block{}
        {
            \textbf{Charlie SubColumn}
        }
        \block{}
        {
            \textbf{Charlie.1 SubColumn}
        }
        \subcolumn{0.33}        
        \block{}
        {
            \textbf{Delta SubColumn}
        }
        \block{}
        {
            \textbf{Delta.1 SubColumn}
        }
        \subcolumn{0.33}        
    \block{}
    {
        \textbf{Gamma SubColumn}
    }
    \block{}
    {
        \textbf{Gamma.1 SubColumn}
    }
    \end{subcolumns}
\end{columns}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

As far as I understand tikzposter, don't use two column-environments on the same page. So I commented out the `\end{columns}\begin{columns}`in the middle of your poster. And of course you can't use the lengths of 0.49 more than two times on one page. Code looks like this:

```
\documentclass[25pt, margin=0mm, innermargin=0mm, blockverticalspace=5mm, colspace=0mm, subcolspace=-20mm]{tikzposter}
\geometry{paperwidth=60in,paperheight=20in}
\makeatletter
\setlength{\TP@visibletextwidth}{\textwidth-2\TP@innermargin}
\setlength{\TP@visibletextheight}{\textheight-2\TP@innermargin}
\makeatother
%\tikzposterlatexaffectionproofoff
\usetitlestyle{Empty} %<-- Deletes the title on the Top of the poster.
\title{}
%\usepackage{multicol}
%\usepackage{tikz}
%\usepackage{wrapfig}
%\setlength{\tabcolsep}{2em}
\begin{document}
\begin{columns}
    \column{0.24}%
        \block{}
    {
        \textbf{First Column}
    }
    \begin{subcolumns}  
    \subcolumn{0.5}         
    \block{}
    {
        \textbf{First SubColumn}
    }
    \block{}
    {
        \textbf{First.1 SubColumn}
    }
   \subcolumn{0.5}         
    \block{}
    {
        \textbf{Second SubColumn}
    }
    \block{}
    {
        \textbf{Second.1 SubColumn}
    }
\end{subcolumns}%
    \column{0.24}
    \block{}
    {
        \textbf{Second Column}
    }
    \begin{subcolumns}  
        \subcolumn{0.5}         
        \block{}
        {
            \textbf{third SubColumn}
        }
        \block{}
        {
            \textbf{third.1 SubColumn}
        }
        \subcolumn{0.5}         
        \block{}
        {
            \textbf{Forth SubColumn}
        }
        \block{}
        {
            \textbf{Forth.1 SubColumn}
        }
\end{subcolumns}
% \end{columns}%
% %----------------------------------------------------------------For Next set of Columns    
% \begin{columns}
    \column{0.24}%
    \block{}
    {
        \textbf{First Column}
    }
    \begin{subcolumns}  
        \subcolumn{0.5}%
        \block{}
        {
            \textbf{Alpha SubColumn}
        }
        \block{}
        {
            \textbf{Alpha.1 SubColumn}
        }
        \subcolumn{0.5}         
        \block{}
        {
            \textbf{Beta SubColumn}
        }
        \block{}
        {
            \textbf{Beta.1 SubColumn}
        }
    \end{subcolumns}
    \column{0.24}
    \block{}
    {
        \textbf{Beta Column}
    }
    \begin{subcolumns}  
        \subcolumn{0.33}        
        \block{}
        {
            \textbf{Charlie SubColumn}
        }
        \block{}
        {
            \textbf{Charlie.1 SubColumn}
        }
        \subcolumn{0.33}        
        \block{}
        {
            \textbf{Delta SubColumn}
        }
        \block{}
        {
            \textbf{Delta.1 SubColumn}
        }
        \subcolumn{0.33}        
    \block{}
    {
        \textbf{Gamma SubColumn}
    }
    \block{}
    {
        \textbf{Gamma.1 SubColumn}
    }
    \end{subcolumns}
\end{columns}
\end{document}
```

[image: tikzposter with subcolumns]

Comment: Sorry, but my requirement is that I need the second \begin{column} content below the first two.
I need to see paper dimension and text size in mind.

Comment: @AbhijeetPattnayak Probably a bug. I didn't find a solution. Write to the maintainers and ask?

Comment: @AbhijeetPattnayak Yes, really buggy.